# Access enum value inside a method of enum class in Kotlin

Tags: enums, kotlin

I have enum class with method declared inside

```
enum class MyEnum {
    VAL1, VAL2, VAL3;

    fun myFunc(): Any{
         // Here I want to access selected value
         // VAL1 in my example
    }
}
```

I can call this method like this

```
MyEnum.VAL1.myFunc()
```

But is it possible inside `myFunc` to get the value method was called on? In my example it's `VAL1`.

Comment: You can use `this`? What's the context of referencing self? If it's to return some value based on "selected" value with a switch (when), then it's better to have a field in the enum and just return its value.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `this` and `this.ordinal` which returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant  
 Also if you do this:

```
fun myFunc(): Any{
    val array = MyEnum.values()
    println(array[this.ordinal])
    println(this)
    return array[this.ordinal]
}
```

and call `MyEnum.VAL2.myFunc()` you will see `VAL2`

Answer (score 1):

Try as follow

```
enum class MyEnum {
    VAL1 {
        override fun myFunc() {
            //do something with VAL1 using this
        }
    },
    VAL2 {
        override fun myFunc() {
            //do something with VAL2 using this
        }
    },
    VAL3 {
        override fun myFunc() {
            //do something with VAL3 using this
        }
    };

    abstract fun myFunc()
}
```